# Issue passing in json object to external API

Tags: json, ajax, api

Firstly I have no control on how the API is constructed, all I need to do is call it basically.

Now I need to pass in the following as shown here:

```
{
            "ConsumerAggregatedAttributes": [
                {
                    "ConsumerAggregatedAttributeID": 28,
                    "ConsumerID": "1159040334",
                    "ApplicationCode": "36363636",
                    "LocaleCode": null,
                    "AttributeCode": "FailedLoginAttemps",
                    "Value": "0",
                    "CreateTS": "2015-12-14 23:53:30.517",
                    "UpdateTS": "2015-12-15 01:12:06.947"
                }
            ],
            "ConsumerID": "1159040334",
            "PersonalQRImageGUID": "a30d62db-0981-4b7c-bed0-4cf66d2fe1a3",
            "PictureMediaGUID": null,
            "Nickname": "testing",
            "LastGPSCoordinate": null,
            "TotalCredit": 0,
            "AvailableCredit": 0,
            "IsActive": true,
            "IsPictureApproved": false,
            "Firstname": "test",
            "Lastname": "test",
            "Username": "test.email@test.com.au",
            "Password": null,
            "Email": "test.email@test.com.au",
            "Mobile": "04145588774",
            "Address": null,
            "City": null,
            "Province": null,
            "PostalCode": null,
            "Country": null,
            "DateOfBirth": null,
            "Gender": null,
            "Language": null,
            "CreateTS": "2015-12-14 23:51:27.143",
            "UpdateTS": "2015-12-15 01:17:22.567",
            "ConsumerTypeCode": "Admin",
            "DefaultLocaleCode": "EN",
            "IsTestUser": false,
            "Distance": null
        }
```

Now my ajax call looks like this:

```
 $http({
        method: 'POST', url: 'https://someUrl.com/servicecol.svc/updateProfile?$expand=ConsumerAggregatedAttributes&LocationID=1&Role=Manager&IsProfileComplete=True', headers: {
            t: ts, // Time Stamp
            vt2: hashInBase64,// Encrypted code
            a: ac, // Account Id
            l: la, // Local
            c: cId // Consumer Id
        },
        data: {
            "ConsumerAggregatedAttributes": [
                {
                    "ConsumerAggregatedAttributeID": 28,
                    "ConsumerID": "1159040334",
                    "ApplicationCode": "36363636",
                    "LocaleCode": null,
                    "AttributeCode": "FailedLoginAttemps",
                    "Value": "0",
                    "CreateTS": "2015-12-14 23:53:30.517",
                    "UpdateTS": "2015-12-15 01:12:06.947"
                }
            ],
            "ConsumerID": "1159040334",
            "PersonalQRImageGUID": "a30d62db-0981-4b7c-bed0-4cf66d2fe1a3",
            "PictureMediaGUID": null,
            "Nickname": "testing",
            "LastGPSCoordinate": null,
            "TotalCredit": 0,
            "AvailableCredit": 0,
            "IsActive": true,
            "IsPictureApproved": false,
            "Firstname": "test",
            "Lastname": "test",
            "Username": "test.email@test.com.au",
            "Password": null,
            "Email": "test.email@test.com.au",
            "Mobile": "04145588774",
            "Address": null,
            "City": null,
            "Province": null,
            "PostalCode": null,
            "Country": null,
            "DateOfBirth": null,
            "Gender": null,
            "Language": null,
            "CreateTS": "2015-12-14 23:51:27.143",
            "UpdateTS": "2015-12-15 01:17:22.567",
            "ConsumerTypeCode": "Admin",
            "DefaultLocaleCode": "EN",
            "IsTestUser": false,
            "Distance": null
        }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.response = data;

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.response = data;
    });
```

Now when I call this function It should pass it like this :

```
https://someUrl.com/servicecol.svc/updateProfile?$expand=ConsumerAggregatedAttributes&LocationID=1&Role=Manager&IsProfileComplete=True
{
"ConsumerAggregatedAttributes": [{
    "ConsumerAggregatedAttributeID": 28,
    "ConsumerID": "1159040334",
    "ApplicationCode": "36363636",
    "LocaleCode": null,
    "AttributeCode": "FailedLoginAttemps",
    "Value": "0",
    "CreateTS": "2015-12-14 23:53:30.517",
    "UpdateTS": "2015-12-15 01:12:06.947"
}],
"ConsumerID": "1159040334",
"PersonalQRImageGUID": "a30d62db-0981-4b7c-bed0-4cf66d2fe1a3",
"PictureMediaGUID": null,
"Nickname": "testing",
"LastGPSCoordinate": null,
"TotalCredit": 0,
"AvailableCredit": 0,
"IsActive": true,
"IsPictureApproved": false,
"Firstname": "test",
"Lastname": "test",
"Username": "test.email@test.com.au",
"Password": null,
"Email": "test.email@test.com.au",
"Mobile": "04145588774",
"Address": null,
"City": null,
"Province": null,
"PostalCode": null,
"Country": null,
"DateOfBirth": null,
"Gender": null,
"Language": null,
"CreateTS": "2015-12-14 23:51:27.143",
"UpdateTS": "2015-12-15 01:17:22.567",
"ConsumerTypeCode": "Admin",
"DefaultLocaleCode": "EN",
"IsTestUser": false,
"Distance": null
}
```

But instead it passes it like this

```
https://someUrl.com/servicecol.svc/updateProfile?$expand=ConsumerAggregatedAttributes&LocationID=1&Role=Manager&IsProfileComplete=True**[object Object]**
```

As you can see at the end of the Url it has object object, and after investigation from my self and the guys that own this API this is the reason why its failing, can any shed any light on how I can get it actually post correctly instead of having [object object] in the url?

Comment: Are you using AngularJS?

Comment: Hey. Thanks for responding, yes I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST data should not be appended to the end of the url, but instead sent through the body of the request. There will be a maximum size limit for the data sent in a url of a GET request.

The result you are trying to achieve in your code above looks like a GET:

```
https://someUrl.com/servicecol.svc/updateProfile?params{JSON}
```

All that JSON data could exceed the limit (possibly 255 bytes), plus it appears you are using POST in your $http method.

Give this a try, I have added comments for the changes I made to your code:

Working fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/jqn5pd9x/1/

```
// Stringify the JSON
var postData = JSON.stringify({
  "ConsumerAggregatedAttributes": [{
    "ConsumerAggregatedAttributeID": 28,
    "ConsumerID": "1159040334",
    "ApplicationCode": "36363636",
    "LocaleCode": null,
    "AttributeCode": "FailedLoginAttemps",
    "Value": "0",
    "CreateTS": "2015-12-14 23:53:30.517",
    "UpdateTS": "2015-12-15 01:12:06.947"
  }],
  "ConsumerID": "1159040334",
  "PersonalQRImageGUID": "a30d62db-0981-4b7c-bed0-4cf66d2fe1a3",
  "PictureMediaGUID": null,
  "Nickname": "testing",
  "LastGPSCoordinate": null,
  "TotalCredit": 0,
  "AvailableCredit": 0,
  "IsActive": true,
  "IsPictureApproved": false,
  "Firstname": "test",
  "Lastname": "test",
  "Username": "test.email@test.com.au",
  "Password": null,
  "Email": "test.email@test.com.au",
  "Mobile": "04145588774",
  "Address": null,
  "City": null,
  "Province": null,
  "PostalCode": null,
  "Country": null,
  "DateOfBirth": null,
  "Gender": null,
  "Language": null,
  "CreateTS": "2015-12-14 23:51:27.143",
  "UpdateTS": "2015-12-15 01:17:22.567",
  "ConsumerTypeCode": "Admin",
  "DefaultLocaleCode": "EN",
  "IsTestUser": false,
  "Distance": null
  });

// Fill these out with your private data
var ts = new Date().getTime();
var vt2 = "dGVzdA==";
var ac = 123;
var la = "en";
var cId = 321;

// Made the keys strings
var postHeaders = {
  "t": ts, // Time Stamp
  "vt2": hashInBase64,// Encrypted code
  "a": ac, // Account Id
  "l": la, // Local
  "c": cId // Consumer Id
}

// Moved the params off of the url into an object
var postParams = {
  "$expand": "ConsumerAggregatedAttributes", 
  "LocationID": 1,
  "Role": "Manager",
  "IsProfileComplete": "True"
}

// Added the params. Simplified by extracting data into external variables.
var req = {
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://someUrl.com/servicecol.svc/updateProfile",
  headers: postHeaders,
  params: postParams,
  data: postData
}

// The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead.  
$http(req).then(function successCallback(response) {
  $scope.response = response;
}, function errorCallback(response) {
   $scope.response = response;
});
```

Your issue could be due to a number of things. APIs can be extremely hard to work with, as everything needs to be sent exactly how the API is expecting it.

Make sure you check your Developer Tool's Console for any errors.

For my fiddle I am using a free service called [Henry's HTTP Post Dumping Server](http://posttestserver.com/) that allows you to see your post information from a server's perspective. You can also use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to try to debug your issue outside of the browser, by passing headers and parameters to the API using different methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I agree API's are a pain to work with especially when you don't have control over them, and the documentation provided is some what limited.